# No Raid feature in Redhat Hypervisor

Tags: raid, software-raid, kernel-panic, fakeraid, rhev

We purchased Supermicro Server "SUPERMICRO CSE-827H-R1400B" . And each of its node has 9TB Storage . And we planned to use this server as a Host for Virtual Machines. So i started to install the hypervisor on each node. And created Raid 5 now Hypervisor presents 5.26 TB .

After installation when i check the intel Raid manager it shows the RAID is in INITIALIZE mode and hypervisor gives kernel panic during boot and hangs

Now we need Raid incase of HDD failure. I know its hypervisor which is breaking raid each time.

Redhat Hypervisor 6.6

[image: Raid Mgr]

[image: Kernel Panic]

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on superuser.com or serverfault.com. To support Intel's RST RAID, which is software RAID with a bit of assistance from firmware, you probably need to install a `mdraid` driver on the hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

this is NOT raid, this is fakeraid, and you should never use it. Either get a proper raid controller, or disable the card, switch it to JBOD mode and use `mdadm` to create software raid.